# How to stop fish shell from underlining path?

Tags: fish

The `fish` shell will underline a path given as an argument to a command such as `ls`.  Is there a way to change that behavior since I find it very ugly?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`fish` underlining valid path by defaul:

```
$ set | grep fish_color_valid_path
fish_color_valid_path --underline
```

You only need to reset it:

```
$ set fish_color_valid_path
$ ls /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Is this overwritten by fish_color_param ? I can't manage to set a color for a valid path